# Creating an array of characters (user-input) through recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I'm creating a program (whose functions must be recursive) which accepts a series of characters from the user, terminated by a period, and displays the characters backwards on the screen. A sample run should give:

```
Enter a character: H
Enter a character: i
Enter a character: .
iH
```

I made a function that reverses an array which takes a character array and its size as parameters.

```
void print_backwards(char a[], int size){
    int i = size-1;
    cout << a[i];
    i--;
    if(i >= 0){
        print_backwards(a, i);
    }
}
```

I have a problem, however, with initializing the character array using recursion. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: didnt get it. int char_count = 2; print_backwards(a, char_count);?

Comment: The print_backwards function only implements the reversing of the character array. In the main function, if you manually declared a character array, {'H', 'i'} and int size = 2, and have print_backwards take these two as parameters, it will display `iH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a homework problem, so I'm not going to solve the problem for you.  However, I can give you a push in the right direction.

Make a function that takes a character array by reference and an offset.
On the first call of the function, give it an offset of zero and pass it the empty array.

The function itself should read a single character from the user.
If the character is a `.`, write a null byte to the current position and return the current offset, else, write the supplied character to the current position, then call the function again with offset+1.
The function will return the length of the input.

The function body will look something like

```
// Get character from user

if ( c == '.' ) {
    input[offset] = '\0';
    return offset;
} else {
    input[offset] = c;
    return thisFunction(input, offset+1);
}
```